# How to take first class using xPath?

Tags: xpath

I have a problem with xPath. I have 8 class `.xyz` and I want to only first class take. I use `//span[@class='xyz']` but this return all 8 classes. How can I take only first class ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! At least provide the original XML that you want to navigate; besides I suggest you to read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you. And sometimes doing that, we can even solve our problem without the need of others. If that occurs, feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but I guess this should work for you:

```
(//span[@class='xyz'])[1]
```

Comment: Possibly dumb question, but why `[1]` and not `[0]`? Are these indices not zero-based?

Comment: @joanis. No, definitely not dumb question. But a known question and issue. In xpath indexation starts with 1. You can see discussions about this here on stackoverflow.com